# Update a view from a nested view?

Tags: swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI, so please go easy on me :)
I am trying to create a view representing a Meal with, at the top, the sum of the carbs, fats and proteins of each Ingredient. The ingredients are presented as a list underneath. In each line, the contribution in nutrients for that ingredient is reported and its grams can be modified. I would like for the sums at the top to change instantaneously when the grams are.

At the moment, the most efficient thing I was able to do is to instantly change only the nutrients in the same line. To update the info on top, I have to get out of the view and re-enter. Is there a way to avoid this, and get an immediate update?

I am using Swift 5.

This is my code (redacted for brevity):

```
struct MealPrepView: View {
    
    let MyColor = Color(UIColor(named: "MyColor") ?? UIColor.black)
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var mealHolder: MealHolder
    @EnvironmentObject var ingredientHolder: IngredientHolder
    
    @State var temporaryMeal: TemporaryMealIngredients = TemporaryMealIngredients()
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var notes: String = ""
    private var newMeal: Bool = false
    
    
    @State private var showAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var showNameInput:Bool = false
    
    init(passedMeal: MealItem? = nil){
        if let meal = passedMeal{
            // there is a meal passed through -> edit mode
            temporaryMeal.ingredients = meal.ingredients ?? []
            newMeal = false
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    Text(String(format: "C: %.1f", temporaryMeal.carbsblocks))
                    Text(String(format: " %.1f g", temporaryMeal.carbs)).foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    Text(String(format: "P: %.1f", temporaryMeal.proteinsblocks))
                    Text(String(format: " %.1f g", temporaryMeal.proteins)).foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack{
                    Text(String(format: "F: %.1f", temporaryMeal.fatsblocks))
                    Text(String(format: " %.1f g", temporaryMeal.fats)).foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Create meal")
            .padding(.top, 20)
            
            Spacer()
            
             
             List{
                 ForEach($temporaryMeal.ingredients){
                 $ingredient in IngredientCellEditQ(passedIngredient: ingredient)
     .environmentObject(ingredientHolder).foregroundColor(MyColor)
             }.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
             }      
        }
    }
```

and the ViewModel:

```
class TemporaryMealIngredients: ObservableObject
{
    
    @Published var ingredients: [IngredientItem] = []
    
    var carbs: Float {
        ingredients.map({$0.carbs}).reduce(0,+)
    }
    var proteins: Float{
        ingredients.map({$0.proteins}).reduce(0,+)
    }
    var fats: Float{
        ingredients.map({$0.fats}).reduce(0,+)
    }
    
    
    // total grams / grams in 1 block
    var carbsblocks: Float {
        carbs / 9
    }
    var proteinsblocks: Float {
        proteins / 7
    }
    var fatsblocks: Float {
        fats / 3
    }
    
    
    func clear(){
        ingredients = []
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The recommended way is to use a view model (a class conforming to `@ObservableObject`) holding the data model and injected into the environment. Then you can modify it from everywhere and the `@Published` properties refresh the observing views.

Comment: I'll modify the question with the ViewModel I'm now using (I think it is a ViewModel?). The problem persists.

Comment: try to think about it like this: View - action -> View Model - change -> Another view updates. Basically both views should not interact directly, they always interact through view model

Comment: `temporaryMeal` must be `@StateObject` and you have to put it into the environment. And what are the other `...Holder` objects for. It looks a bit confusing.

Comment: MealHolder and IngredientHolder -from what I gathered following a tutorial, keep in mind- allow me to create a "database" of meals and ingredients. In another view, I have a list of ingredients and a list of meals created with them.